# Slow volume fade-in when playing audio tracks

Tags: pulseaudio, volume-control

I have a system running fresh installed Ubuntu 14.04.1

When a music track starts to play, the volume is gradually increased. It takes about 2 seconds to hear anything and 3 seconds to reach full volume.

When playing short tracks this is really annoying.

Is it a pulse-audio setting? How can I make the volume increasement go faster?

---

Thanks for your response.

I tested the following applications:

- youtube video in firefox browser
- play song in Rythmbox
- play sound in Anki

As far as I can see all (sound related) applications suffer from this.

Comment: What program are you using to play the music? Does it happen with any program?

Comment: Have face the same problem while playing any video file as well? If possible, try to reinstall the audio drive and check it once again.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is due to pulseaudio suspending the respective audio interface, presumably for power saving reasons.

Try editing your pulse audio config (for me /etc/pulse/default.pa) and comment out this line to disable this feature:

```
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

Then restart Pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: I had a symptom where Ubuntu audio starts silently "ramps up" in about 2 seconds,  including the test sound from the system sound settings.  After removing the module noted above, sounds play crisply and right away. Thanks.